# FIle formats in netstream

Tags: netstream

what are the file frmats supported in netstream, is it that only FLV is supported of how about .avi,.mp4 an all that.....

Also, whare are the codec supported here, other than on2 & sorensen.....

Please let me know anything that you know....

Thx,
AJ

Answer (score 0):

Well u have to use any media server to support other codecs
like 
Flash Media Server
Wowza Server
Red5.